# How to prevent the user from download anything on my website if he is not registered?

Tags: asp.net

I'm making a project on ASP.NET and I want that if the user is not registered with my site or not Login then he/she will not able to download. If I'm using session ID then I've to pass it on every link and page so is there a simple way to accomplish it?

Comment: Use the built in authentication system.  Require registration to view the content of the website.

Comment: Does your site allow unregistered users to see the page containing the download link?  Or is it behind a login page?

Comment: @Gibron yes, unregistered user can see the download link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the ASP.NET stock authentication system, you can just add a tag like this to your `<system.web>` element in web.config:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 0):

StriplingWarriors answer will work for all unauthenticated users but if you are attempting to restrict specific users from doing/viewing specific things on the site (and assuming you are using the ASP.NET membership API to manage users) you can just check User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

Comment: you can use @StriplingWarrior's solution at any level of your website. For example, if you don't want someone to download any images or zip files, you can just create a web.config file within your "assets" folder and use the `authorization` config.

Comment: Chase is Correct. You can also create a `<location>` element within your main web.config if you like to keep all the config in the same file.

Comment: Agree with Chase and StriplingWarrior, you should put any resources you want to secure into a specific folder and lock it down using the authorization config. If you have links to those files as part of your public site you can use the IsAuthenticated property to either hide those links from unauthenticated users or display a message requesting that they login.